# alternative to EVENT.DEACTIVATE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

EVENT.DEACTIVATE doesn't work with safari in mac, is there any possible way to do this. (MouseEvent.MOUSE_LEAVE is not the same as detect when user lost the focus of the window) so I ran out of alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the blur event via JavaScript and dispatch it to your SWF via ExternalInterface.